# WPF: What kind of binding should I use to associate a textbox to a dependency object declared in code?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a DependencyObject class

```
public class TestDependency : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TestDateTimeProperty ...

    public DateTime TestDateTime {get... set..}
}
```

my window is like this

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window{

    public TestDependency td;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        td = new TestDependency();
        td.TestDateTime = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

If I wanna bind the TestDateTime property of MainWindow's dependency object td (public TestDependency td;) to a textbox in Xaml, how do I bind it? This is what I am doing now

`<TextBlock Name="tb" Text="{Binding Source = td, Path=TestDateTime, TargetNullValue=novalue}"/>`

It doesn't work at all. Anyone knows what I need to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you'll need to define `td` as a property rather than a field, since you can only bind to properties:

```
public TestDependency td { get; private set; }
```

Then, make sure you set the data context in your window's constructor:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    td = new TestDependency();
    td.TestDateTime = DateTime.Now;
    this.DataContext = this;

    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Lastly, set the binding in XAML:

```
<TextBlock Name="tb" Text="{Binding Path=td.TestDateTime}" />
```

Comment: It Works! Thanks! Now I wonder why it didn't work when i declared the dependency object as a field? And, after changing it to a property, does it have any difference in functionality compared to being as a field?

Comment: As I mentioned, WPF data binding isn't designed to work with fields, only properties. In this case there is no difference in functionality - the property is simply an abstraction for the field.

Comment: ahhh ok, now I get it. I notice you declared `InitializeComponent()` at the bottom of the constructor, is this the standard practice when setting DataContext in the constructor?

Comment: Yes, it's actually recommended to do so, since otherwise the binding will be attempted twice: once when `InitializeComponent` is called, and another when `DataContext` is set. This way, the binding is only performed once.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to set the `DataContext` in your MainWindow.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    td = new TestDependency();
    td.TestDateTime = DateTime.Now;

    DataContext = this;
}
```

Use a property instead of a field for `td`:

```
public TestDependency td { get; set; }
```

And don't use `Source` for your binding, use the `Path`:

```
<TextBlock Name="tb" Text="{Binding Path= td.TestDateTime, TargetNullValue=novalue}"/>
```